# Retain text at N, N+1 and header at N+2th row for multiple excel sheets?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl, pandas.excelwriter

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
SHEET SUBJECT Listings for 2010 hi bla bla,,,,,,
order_number,,,,,,
Date,cust,region,Abr,Number,         
12/01/2010,Company_Name,Somecity,Chi,36,
12/02/2010,Company_Name,Someothercity,Nyc,156,

df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')
```

From the above dataframe, you can see that the 1st two rows (`narrative text`) are just description but header/column names starts from 1st row index

So, I tried the below

```
df.columns = df.iloc[1] #assign actual column headers
df.drop(index=[0,1], inplace = True) #drop the actual column header row and also narrative text line from dataframe
# do some manipulation of data below (thanks to jezrael for the below code)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('duck_data.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter')
for (cust,reg), v in df.groupby(['cust','region']):
    v.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f"DATA_{cust}_{reg}",index=False)   
writer.save()
```

the above works fine only when there is only headers, the problem is am not able to retain the narrative text (ex: `SHEET SUBJECT Listings for 2010 hi bla bla` and `order_number,,,,,,` in my output excel file `(duck_data.xlsx)`

How can I retain these two narrative texts in each of the worksheet of `duck_data.xlsx` (output file) and store the column headers from 3rd cell of excel file?

I expect my output to be like as shown below. You can see that the data is different in both the worksheets of output excel file but I have retained the narrative text, header throughout for all the worksheets of output excel file.

Is there anyway to copy this text to each sheet based on the number of sheets generated? Any other approach/idea to retain these texts in each sheet?

[image]  [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#add text to variable from first column in original DataFrame 
text = df.columns[0]
#add order no to variable by first value of first column
order_no = df.iloc[0,0]
df.columns = df.iloc[1] #assign actual column headers
df.drop(index=[0,1], inplace = True)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('duck_data.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter')
for (cust,reg), v in df.groupby(['cust','region']):
    #strating row for write data is 2 (changed default 0)
    v.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f"DATA_{cust}_{reg}", index=False, startrow = 2)   
    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets[f"DATA_{cust}_{reg}"]
    #to first cell in excel write text variable
    worksheet.write(0, 0, text)
    worksheet.write(1, 0, order_no)
writer.save()
```

Comment: I think we should start from row =2 because we have two text lines. I guess you have used only one text. In sample output, we have two text lines. I dropped the `order_number` text line from df because it will impact our data manipulation but it should be used for final display (in output file).

Comment: @TheGreat - You are right, I miss it. Tested and added to answer.

Comment: I get this error `KeyError: '[0 1] not found in axis'`. When I give `axis=0`, it still throws the same error

Comment: @TheGreat - can you test if change `df.drop(index=[0,1], inplace = True)` to `df = df.iloc[2:]` ?

Comment: yes, this works now. But one quick question. If there are `text` that appears in [0.0] and [0,35] and [0,44]x, what can we do? meaning text appears in the same row but at multiple parts?

Comment: I can just create additional variables and write them accordingly. Am I right?

Comment: @TheGreat - is possible join it?

Comment: need `df.iloc[0, 0] + ' ' + df.iloc[0, 35] + ' ' + df.iloc[0,44]` ?

Comment: @TheGreat - yes, if need separately values you are right

Comment: @TheGreat - I try found problem but is seem it is bug :(

Comment: @TheGreat - I try `ws = sales.sheets[0]
ws.range('G5').options(index=False).value = df1.astype(str).reset_index(drop=True` and o luck :(

Comment: @TheGreat - yop, same like your.

Comment: yes, output is expected, because it set values from `G5`. pandas not see data from excel, only write.

Comment: I added my answer to that post. Can see whether you can improve the solution/efficient? I can mark your answer (and remove my answer)

Comment: I see, really not easy :(

Comment: Okay, no worries Jezrael. Appreciate your inputs. Just wanted to seek your opinion on whether we can imprvoe further.